# How do you say when you need to put money on your travel card?

Tags: phrase-request

Like MetroCard in New York, they provide travel card which you can pay fairs through a prepaid card. But after some uses, the money inside the card decreases and you need to put more money into it. Let's say you want to put 20 dollars more in it. How do you ask that requirement to a staff working in the subway? I may use sentences such as I'd like to recharge 20 dollars, I want to top up my card 20 dollars, I want to reload my card 20 dollars.

What expression do you use usually in everyday life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are looking for is **refilling**. When I have to refill my MetroCard (card used in NYC Subway) through a station booth, I would simply say “I would like to refill my MetroCard with 20 dollars” but being more polite I would ask “could you please refill my MetroCard with 20 dollars?”.

---

**[Here's how Refills work](http://web.mta.info/metrocard/7day_30dayRefill.htm)**

> Refilling is easy at a vending machine. Just press “MetroCard”, then “Refill Your Card” and follow the instructions. You can also refill your card at any station booth.

Comment: In British English, we would say _top up_.

Comment: @KateBunting I see. I remembered that 'top up' was used somewhere but I never figured out in which country they used the phrase.